# Большая разница в размере структуры на разных системах и разрядностях, компиляторах

Tags: c++, c, .net, gcc, mingw

Присутствует сруктура из си заголовка, такого вида:

```
typedef struct AVCodecDescriptor {
    int      id;
    int type;
    /**
     * Name of the codec described by this descriptor. It is non-empty and
     * unique for each codec descriptor. It should contain alphanumeric
     * characters and '_' only.
     */
    const char      *name;
    /**
     * A more descriptive name for this codec. May be NULL.
     */
    const char *long_name;
    /**
     * Codec properties, a combination of AV_CODEC_PROP_* flags.
     */
    int             props;
    /**
     * MIME type(s) associated with the codec.
     * May be NULL; if not, a NULL-terminated array of MIME types.
     * The first item is always non-NULL and is the preferred MIME type.
     */
    const char *const *mime_types;
    /**
     * If non-NULL, an array of profiles recognized for this codec.
     * Terminated with FF_PROFILE_UNKNOWN.
     */
    const struct AVProfile *profiles;
} AVCodecDescriptor;
```

При подсчете на пальцах, на x86 системе, размер структуры равен 28 байт, следовательно, на x64 размер должен перемножаться на 2, но в итоге при вызове `sizeof` получаем не 56 байт, а 48.

Почему так происходит и как такое может отразиться при использовании таких размеров для структуры [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)?

P.S. Разные компиляторы отдали одно и тоже значение:

gcc x64 : `Size of AVCodecDescriptor is: 48 bytes`

mingw32 : `Size of AVCodecDescriptor is: 28 bytes`

cygwin x64 : `Size of AVCodecDescriptor is: 48 bytes`

Как правильно подойти к решению данной задачи, дабы не лезть за пределы памяти структуры, и так что бы размер структуры не был слишком велик?

Comment: В 64-bit тут будет одна дырка размером 4 байта после `int             props;` (`sizeof(int)` == 4) из-за выравнивания следующего указателя на 8. Все остальное выровнено. А что вы считаете слишком великим размером?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` что на 32, что на 64 разрядах будет 4 байта. Поменяется только размер указателя + возможное выравнивание на 8 байт.

Если очень нужно ужаться (так ли уж важны вам эти байты?), то используйте выравнивание на 4 байта - будет 44 байта.

Comment: У него указатели восьмибайтные, нельзя сделать выравнивание меньше.

Comment: @ixSci Как *размер* указателя связан со значением в нем? См. https://ideone.com/JZ63aC - что тут не так?

Comment: Размер указателя напрямую связан со значением в нём — какой размер указателя, такой и адрес там хранится (говоря языком не стандарта). Что касается Вашего примера: любое обращение к члену-указателю упакованной структуры получается через unaligned access, что есть UB ([basic.align] стандарта).